# prometheus with node_exporter sidecar openshift

Tags: openshift, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I tried to deploy prometheus pod with node_exporter sidecar but when I use the volumeMounts on sidecar node_exporter container it gives me "Multi-attach error" cannot mount or no bound.
I want to use node-exporter belong with all my pods/apps in order to have usage disk metrics, in openshift we don't have any pvc disk usage monitoring metrics and is very annoying.

**my yaml.config:**

```
 containers:
    - args:
        - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
      command:
        - /bin/prometheus
      image: ${DOCKER_REPOSITORY}/prom/prometheus:v2.0.0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: prometheus
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          protocol: TCP
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /prometheus
          name: prometheus-data
        - mountPath: /etc/prometheus
          name: prometheus-configmap
      image: quay.io/prometheus/node-exporter
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: node-exporter-sidecar
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9100
          protocol: TCP
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /prometheus
          name: prometheus-data
     - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
       apiVersion: v1
       metadata:
         name: prometheus-ls-data
       spec:
         accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
         resources:
           requests:
             storage: "${PV_SIZE}"
         storageClassName: "cinder-performant"
```

Answer (score 0):

Node exporter is deployed as part of default openshift monitoring stack and its lifecycle is managed by cluster-monitoring-operator. It is deployed as a daemonset and runs as pod on each node to extract its metrics.

Have you installed or  deployed default prometheus monitoring stack in your cluster if not you just need to deploy the default stack and node exporter will be installed as part of that.

Comment: We have a lot of metrics for the cluster but we don’t have for PVC  used disk … space left

Answer (score 0):

Following Prometheus Metrics are exposed as part of default openshift monitoring stack ( as Kubelet Target ) . you can use this to calculate the usage of your pvs .

kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes
kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes
kubelet_volume_stats_inodes
kubelet_volume_stats_inodes_used

Cant you see the above metrics in your prometheus instance.

Comment: i don;t have any "kubelet_ " metric in /metrics

Comment: Which openshift version are you using & have you deployed default monitoring stack using ansible  playbook.

Comment: OpenShift Master: v3.9.51 ,  Kubernetes Master: v1.9.1, OpenShift Web Console: v3.9.51
I don't have admin on this cluster and I'm sure the admin did the deploy of the default monitoring stack with ansible playbook

Comment: Then ask the admin to setup that for you. It’s easier for them as it’s default metrics and they can setup volume usage alerts for your namespace.

Comment: he don't know how to do it, the default metrics are already activated but these with volume metrics do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In openshift 3.9 volume metrics are exposed by prometheus as below

[image]

So search for these metrics.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please see the volume metrics i have in the cluster from the Prometheus

Comment: is this the prometheus deployed by ansible at platform level or is it something you are running in your namespace ?

Comment: deployed by ansible :)